# xsl stylesheet not visible on browser for xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

After seeing many similar questions, i was able to solve the errors seen and now content is visible on browser. But i am not able to see use of stylesheet or styling not observed, it just displays as plain text. Please assist.

**[xml file=content.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet content-type="text/xsl" href="xslcontent.xsl"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
<title>Ram Sailee</title>
<artist>Bipul Chhetri</artist>
<country>Nepal</country>
<company>Songs Nepal</company>
<price>300</price>
<year>2014</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Columbia</company>
<price>10.90</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

**[xsl file=xslcontent.xsl]**

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>

<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th style="text-align:left" >Title</th>
<th style="text-align:left" >Artist</th>
</tr>

<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
</tr>


</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>

</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Following is the output :**
[output seen in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCjKc.png)

Comment: Is that an exact copy of your XSLT file? There is a `?` missing from the XML declaration: it should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, not `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : yes, it is the exact copy. I corrected the mistake, still its the same.

Comment: Which browser is it?

Comment: Its google chrome, but i have also checked with Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this part in your XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet content-type="text/xsl" href="xslcontent.xsl"?>
```

to:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslcontent.xsl"?>
```

Comment: If i change it to <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslcontent.xsl"?>, then all content disappears, blank page seen.

Comment: Yeah it works now in Firefox, thank you very much. Now, i shall try more. But, what might be the reason for not working in chrome.

Comment: There is a security issue in Chrome - do a search.

Comment: Are you running this in filestore or in an HTTP server? Some browsers make it difficult or impossible to do this kind of thing in filestore. You may be able to adjust security settings but it's usually easier to create a local web server.